# Spanning of points in projective space

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let's $S=k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ be a standard graded ploynomial ring and $k$ be a alg. closed field. Consider the following Veronese map $\nu_4:\mathbb{P}^2=\mathbb{P}(S_1)\to\mathbb{P}(S_4)=\mathbb{P}^{14}$. I know that the spanning of six points will give us a $6-dimensional$ vector space and then we have $\mathbb{P}^5$. Suppose that $\{[L_1^4],...,[L_6^4]\}$ be a set of six generic points in $\mathbb{P}^{14}$.

I am going to show that $$Span([L_1^4],...,[L_6^4])=<[L_1^4],...,[L_6^4]>_k=\mathbb{P}^5$$
Thank you for your helps.

Comment: What do you want to show exactly ?

Comment: @N.H. Spanning of six points in $\mathbb{P}^{14}$ gives us $\mathbb{P}^5$

Comment: This is not true for all point $p_1, \dots, p_6$ (e.g if they are on the same line). Do you mean you want to prove that for any 6 points on the Veronese variety, they span a $5$-plane ?

Comment: And in fact I don't think it is true, but $5$ points will span a $\mathbb P^4$.  The proof is here : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157096/can-the-veronese-variety-of-degree-k-have-k1-linearly-dependent-points

Comment: @N.H. this points are distinct and linearly independents.

Comment: you should add these extra details into the main body of the question, also $\textrm{Span}$, `\textrm{Span}`